# lost in debug ... can't stop execution

Tags: stack, call, windbg, system-calls, cpu-registers

I am trying to understand why an installation file hangs up using Windbg, but I am at a point where I can't stop the execution.

As background, I had already been able to install this program on the same PC, but for some reason I had then uninstalled, and now I can't re-install it (I tried to clean up everything from the old installation, incl. registry). Now this setup.exe starts and stays idle among the running processes without doing anything.

But let's go to the actual question. I am trying to use Windbg for the first time (I only had some practice with the old 8086 debug at DOS-time :-), so please bear with me if I'm asking something straightforward).

I have tracked the code up to a point where I have a RET code. I am able to stop the debugger at the RET instruction, but as soon as I "step into" the RET, the execution starts and does not stop, while I was expecting it to just go to the instruction following the previous CALL. From how I see things, it seems that after the RET the execution goes somewhere else ... how is it possible? Also, just before the RET there is a SYSCALL that I don't fully understand ... can it have an impact?

This is the portion of the code I am examining at the moment:

```
ntdll!NtTerminateThread:
00007ff9`fc8b5b20 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
00007ff9`fc8b5b23 b853000000      mov     eax,53h
00007ff9`fc8b5b28 f604250803fe7f01 test    byte ptr [SharedUserData+0x308 (00000000`7ffe0308)],1
00007ff9`fc8b5b30 7503            jne     ntdll!NtTerminateThread+0x15 (00007ff9`fc8b5b35)
00007ff9`fc8b5b32 0f05            syscall
00007ff9`fc8b5b34 c3              ret
00007ff9`fc8b5b35 cd2e            int     2Eh
00007ff9`fc8b5b37 c3              ret
```

I am stuck at the first RET instruction, at address 5b34.
At this time, this is the stack call:

```
00000000`0203fc38 00007ff9`fc86c63e ntdll!NtTerminateThread+0x14
00000000`0203fc40 00007ff9`fc8d903a ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x4e
00000000`0203fc80 00007ff9`fc86c5c5 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x5a
00000000`0203fcb0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x45
```

so my understanding is that execution should continue at address 00007ff9`fc86c63e. However, even if I add a BP at this address, or if I just go for a trace, the execution continues and keeps running some idle loop until I hit the "pause" button in windbg, after which it resume at a completely different address.

In case the registers are relevant, here are some of them:

```
rax: 353000
rbx: 0
rcx: 0
rdx: 0
rsp: 203fc38
rdi: 7ff9c8d8fe0
rip: 7ff9fc8b5b34
```

So, eventually, where am I wrong? How can I see where the code goes after this RET?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Bob

Comment: capture a dmp (taskmgr / ProcessExplorer), open it in windbg and run **!analyze -v -hang** to start hang debugging.

Answer (score 0):

when a thread exits the execution wont return to the return address
the system is free to schedule another thread that is ready in the process
the stack shows NtTerminateThread on the stack it is a function that does not return
__declspec noreturn foo (...) ;

btw when you say it goes elsewhere do you mean the app keeps running and is not terminated if so hit ctrl+break and check what other threads are doing 
ie if usermode `~*kb` should show all the threads callstack

answering the comment about where it goes
`process` is a `collection of threads`
each thread has a stack and each thread gets a bit of time to execute `from the scheduler (thread quantum)`

each thread that has a lower priority can be preempted by `threads xxxx ,yyy ,zzz with higher priorities` `by interrupts by apcs , dpcs etc`

when a thread has completed its quantum or is preempted by some vip cavalcade happening to travel on the road that this poor thread is walking
a trap is made `_KTRAP` and this poor threads position `EIP` is filled into it and put in a waiting threads barricade
when the vip cavalcade's dust has settled police open the barricade and let the poor thread walk from where it stopped

for such gory details you may need a kernel debugging setup and may need to control your process from a kernel debugger

when you hit the return os sees the thread is dead and has no return address 
so it checks the `!ready` threads and selects the highest priority thread and provides it a quantum to enjoy

so before hitting the return address check what all other threads are doing in your app set an appropriate break on threads of interest and hit the return when the other thread executes its quantum your break will get hit

Comment: Thanks blabb, if I understand correctly what you say, upon the execution of the RET code the thread is terminated and the execution moves to some other thread ... is there any way to know to which other thread it moves? i.e., the CPU should have this new address somewhere, either in the registers, the stack, or some other memory location ... do you know which one?

Comment: scheduling is a prerogative of the operating system's kernel you can only see the call stacks of your thread and break on the probable return address if your process is not terminated one of the breaks will be hit i also  added some theory to the answer for reference

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I see I have lots of homeworks to do ... I'll play around a bit and see if I am able to follow your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

**You're looking at the wrong thread!**

From the partial output you supplied seems like you're attaching to a running process (rather than start it from the debugger). To break into a running process the debugger injects a thread into the target process that basically contains a hardcoded `int 3` instruction and not much more.

It does it by calling `ntdll!RtlpCreateUserThreadEx` (the internal undocumented native parallel of `CreateRemoteThread`) supplying `ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin` as the start address for the new thread.

The sole purpose of this synthetic thread is to generate the breakpoint exception. This exception causes the operating system to stop running the target process and passes control to the debugger. After it does this it's not needed anymore and it commits suicide.

What you're supposed to do at this point is probably switch to your thread of interest using [~s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565430(v=vs.85).aspx) command, set breakpoints and then continue execution.

If try to step through this synthetic thread it will just end, and then the process will continue doing whatever it was doing before you broke into it, which is pretty much the opposite of what you want,

That's what this stack means:

> ```
> 00000000`0203fc38 00007ff9`fc86c63e ntdll!NtTerminateThread+0x14
> 00000000`0203fc40 00007ff9`fc8d903a ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x4e
> 00000000`0203fc80 00007ff9`fc86c5c5 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x5a
> 00000000`0203fcb0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x45
> ```

`ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart` is the real user-mode entry point of all user-mode threads and you can see that it just called `ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin` after which you continued a bit until the thread finally ends itself.